# How to bind image deleting to a key in feh?

Tags: feh

I have a problem in feh. When I hit 'CTRL+DELETE' the file is not deleted. Nothing happens at all (according to the manual it should remove the file from disk and from the filelist). If I hit just DELETE then the file is removed from the filelist but not from disk.

In order to properly delete the file, I am thinking of binding the remove command to a number key like this:

`feh --draw-exif -F -d --action1 ";rm %F"`

The image is properly deleted. However, the moment I hit 1, feh closes:

```
feh WARNING: IMG_1902.JPG - File does not exist
feh ERROR: failed to reload image
```

How can I remove the file from disk but not have feh choke on this?

Comment: Hmm, `feh` on OpenBSD via ports unlinks an opened file with control+delete for me. Do you have any custom rc files or aliases that might change that behaviour?

Comment: You were right! I had the delete command remapped to the 'd' key in ~/.config/feh/keys! Thanks! I can just use the `d` key and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon, it instructs feh to reload the image, which is in the meantime gone :-).